# Oauth2 for Node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I find myself in need of a `Oauth2` library for `node.js`. Could someone share their opinion on which library is best and most simple to use or can I perform the request without a library? I need it to perform a single request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[passport.js](http://passportjs.org) has good documentation and supports most common providers.